# Test for files containing certain numbers on its names

Tags: bash, shell-script

Suppose that the folder `$folder` contains the files `2012-01,...,2012-N1,2013-01,...,2013-N2` and so on.

I'd like my script to ask for a natural number `M` and:

```
if the files 20M-* exist
then ask for other natural number M2 and
   if the file 20M-M2 exists
   then open it
else warning msg
```

Since the files change a lot, my `case` test is not so dynamical.

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Any particular shell?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, I guess that it is bash. I'm using Lubuntu.

Comment: Then it might be dash. Don't guess.

Comment: What should I do to know my shell?

Comment: What interpreter are you using in the script?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, sorry. I'm completely newbie on this. I'm trying to learn and create some scripts to help me with my files. I have no idea what you're asking. I just write the script on geany and execute it on the terminal. My first line is `#!/bin/bash`

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you could do this way more elegantly... exercise left for the reader. :P

```
echo M?
read M
for f in 20"$M"-*
do
    if [ -e "$f" ]
    then
        echo M2?
        read M2
        for f in 20"$M"-"$M2"
        do
            if [ -e "$f" ]
            then
                echo SUCCESS
                cat "$f"
                exit
            fi
        done
        echo FAIL: There is no file for 20"$M"-"$M2"
        exit 1
    fi
    echo FAIL: There is no file for 20"$M-*"
    exit 1
done
```

Comment: Just one question: if I have 100 files `20"$M"*` the loop will ask me for `M2` 100 times?

Comment: It would, if it didn't `break` or `exit`, or (if you put it inside a function) `return`.